# exsl:date-year in OS X

Tags: xml, macos, perl, xslt, darwin

As mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38852721/1410711), I am trying to transform my input xml document using Perl and libXSLT. However, when I try to run the same Perl script on OS X with little addition of following in my xsl file under the

```
 <xsl:variable name="current-year">
            <xsl:value-of select="date:year()"/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

I get following error.

```
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function year not found
Unregistered function
xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
runtime error: file trans.xsl line 24 element value-of
XPath evaluation returned no result.
```

My XSLT file header has following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" media-type="text/xml"/>
```

Running `Perl -v` fetches me following

`This is perl, v5.8.8 built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
Copyright 1987-2006, Larry Wall....`

and running `uname -a` fetches me following

`Darwin machine-maci 15.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

Why is this error showing up? I thought [OS X Vendor](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/apple_listens_to_community_add.html)  has already exsl extensions to their libXSLT. Aren't exsl extensions supported yet?

**UPDATE**

I tweaked my example a little bit and I got the output as Vendor :- libxslt as suggested by comments below.

Comment: The link regarding Safari is irrelevant if you're running libxslt through command line or Perl. Anyway, I am not able to reproduce your problem. What do you get as the result of `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/>`?

Comment: I got following error on line where I try to use `exsl:document` (below which I use the `system-property` as per your suggestion)
`runtime error: file trans.xsl line 30 element document
xsltApplySequenceConstructor: failed to find extension document`

Comment: I don't recall recommending you include `exsl:document` (or anything else) in this test. Anyway, I suggest you edit your question and provide **full**, step-by-step instructions how to reproduce your problem - see: [mcve].

Comment: @michael.hor257k I tweaked my example a little bit and I got the output as `Vendor :- libxslt`

Comment: What's the output of `perl -MXML::LibXSLT -le 'print $XML::LibXSLT::VERSION'` and `perl -MXML::LibXSLT -le 'print XML::LibXSLT::HAVE_EXSLT()'`?

Comment: @nwellnhof The outputs are `1.62` and `Can't locate auto/XML/LibXSLT/HAVE_EXSLT.al in @INC (@INC contains: ....all the Perl directories... .) at -e line 1` respectively.

Comment: This is an ancient version of `XML::LibXSLT` from 2006. Maybe it wasn't compiled with EXSLT support but it's hard to tell because the HAVE_EXSLT function was added only later.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare date as extension element too:

```
extension-element-prefixes="exsl date"
```

Your declared xalan namespace probably will not be necessary when using libxslt. Otherwise that would probably have to be added to the extension-element-prefixes also.

Comment: I still get the same error even when I add the date to `extension-element-prefixes`. :(

Comment: Hm libxslt doc states "It also implements most of the EXSLT set of processor-portable extensions functions" and on the exslt page libxslt is listed as implementor of date:year... BTW you could write `<xsl:variable name="current-year" select="date:year()"/>` - Maybe it's best to follow michael.hor257k's suggestion to post a complete (minimal) example

Comment: I actually tweaked my example and I got the output for his suggestions. Please see my latest comment.

Comment: well I can't see why it should not work at the moment