# Perl 5.20.2 with libXSLT 1.94 error

Tags: macos, perl, xslt, exslt

I have pretty recent Perl version installed on my

OS X machine

```
% uname -a 
Darwin X-maci 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

as follows

```
% /$path/perl -v
This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 2 (v5.20.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level

Copyright ....
```

I also have recent version of libXSLT installed as follows

```
% /$path/perl -MXML::LibXSLT -le 'print $XML::LibXSLT::VERSION'
1.94
```

and I also get

```
% /$path/perl -MXML::LibXSLT -le 'print XML::LibXSLT::HAVE_EXSLT()'
1
```

I already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341672/exsldate-year-in-os-x) to explain my use case. 
Essentially, I am trying to access the EXSL extensions (`exsl:date-year(),exsl:document`) in my XSL file. Since I had a pretty old version of Perl and libXSLT at that time, there was no resolution to the problem.

Now I have updated my Perl and libXSLT versions and still I get this error message whenever I try to use the extension(s)

```
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function year not found
Unregistered function
xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
runtime error: file trans.xsl line 14 element value-of
XPath evaluation returned no result.
 at Transform.pl line 43.
```

Is this a known problem  with above OSX + Perl + libXSLT version combination ?

PS:
Interestingly, [this page](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/X/XML-LibXSLT.html) does not mention the results for `darwin-thread-multi-2level` for `version 5.20.2`.

**UPDATE**

1) Perl file

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path;
use File::Spec;
use File::Basename;
use XML::LibXSLT;
use XML::LibXML;
use Getopt::Std;

my $isfile;

my ($xmlfile,$xsltfile,$samplefile) = qw/ Example.xml trans.xsl sample.xml/;
my %opts = ();
getopts('o:',\%opts);

my $outPath = $opts{'o'};
die "File not specified" if !defined($outPath);

if(-f $samplefile)
{
    $isfile = "true";
    print "File is present\n";
}
else
{
    $isfile = "false";
    print "File is absent\n";
}

my %args = ( "isfile" => $isfile,"outpath" => $outPath, );
my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new;
my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet_file($xsltfile);

my $security = XML::LibXSLT::Security->new();
$security->register_callback( read_file  => sub { return 1;} );
$security->register_callback( write_file => sub { return 1;} );
$security->register_callback( create_dir => sub { return 1;} );

$stylesheet->security_callbacks( $security );

XML::LibXSLT->register_function("urn:foo", "bar",\&invalue);

my $results  = $stylesheet->transform_file($xmlfile,XML::LibXSLT::xpath_to_string(%{args}));

sub invalue
{
    my $var = shift;
    return $var + 2;
}    
0;
```

2) XSL file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
xmlns:foo="urn:foo"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" media-type="text/xml"/>

<xsl:param name="isfile"/>
<xsl:param name="outpath"/>

<xsl:variable name="current-year">
    <xsl:value-of select="date:year()"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="$isfile = 'true'">
        <exsl:document href = "{$outpath}" method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes">
            Article:- <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set(/Article/Title)|exsl:node-set(/Article/Title)/@context"/>
            Authors:- <xsl:apply-templates select="/Article/Authors/Author"/>
            Perl function Output :- <xsl:value-of select="foo:bar(234)"/>
        </exsl:document>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You forgot to provide the code and data that produces that output...

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but `extension-element-prefixes="exsl"` should be `extension-element-prefixes="exsl date"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following stylesheet (on any input) and report the result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
extension-element-prefixes="date">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <test>
        <proc>
            <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/>
        </proc>
        <year>
            <xsl:value-of select="function-available('date:year')"/>
        </year>
    </test>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

*Not an answer, but needed the space.*

Comment: No result is displayed when the script is run. :(

Comment: That is very strange - please try again with the updated stylesheet.

Comment: I got the output after I changed my Perl script to use `output_as_bytes` API. The output is `libxslt` and `false`.